# How to setup the element borders in my case

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to create a border on top of another element's border.

I have something like the following

html

```
<table class='table'>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td> 
        <td class="pick">123</td> 
        <td>123</td> 
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="second" style="text-align:center;" colspan='3'>123</td> 
    </tr>

</table>
```

css

```
.pick {
    border-bottom:solid 5px green;
}

.second {
    border:solid 5px red !important;    
    background-color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8zt8sb3/1/

Basically I want to create a gap look for the `<td>` that has a class 'pick'. Everything works fine on every browser but the red border will cover the green border in IE which means there is no gap. Is there anyways to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this property:

```
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: @BonJon sorry, try the new one. I noticed your code on the example is different to the one on jsFiddle, my mistake.